# How do websites change their content dynamically?

Tags: html, css

Quick question. Beginner web designer, please tell me how sites like this one:
http://workwankers.com/  have "automated" source code. What I mean is, as I interact with the site, the code will change. The above example is perfect; as you scroll, new things transition and come into play. Is this one technique/language? Is this multiple languages being used together?

Very confused, I do not see how this can be done in html and css alone.

Comment: It's called JavaScript.

Comment: Given the URL of that link, could you clarify whether it is SFW? :)

Comment: @ChrisW. -- I just play it safe, no external links are SFW :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done using HTML and CSS alone.
The techniques you see are usually done using Javascript, or one of the many Javascript libraries out there.

If you'd care to learn more about web design, you might consider this link:
http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web

Additionally, if you'd like to learn Javascript, you might try this one:
http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript

Comment: OK, thankyou. I figured it might be JaveScript, clearly I have 0 knowledge on it. Thankyou.

Comment: Right on, thanks for the quick reply and helpful links. Have been meaning to learn JavaScript, gunna use those links as a good place to start. :thumbup:

Comment: @user3005676 You're very welcome.  I've suggested those links to many a beginner before.  They really are pretty decent starting points, and you can't complain about the price (free) haha.

Comment: Ha free is the only way I'd have it. I am a firm believer you can learn anything on the interweb. Thanks again Charlie.

Answer (score 1):

The effects you see can be accomplished by the manipulation of **HTML**'s **DOM** through the mixed use of **CSS**, **JavaScript / jQuery**, and **AJAX**.

---

### [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)

> (**H**)yper
>
> (**T**)ext
>
> (**M**)arkup
>
> (**L**)anguage

**HTML** is the main markup language for creating web pages and other information that can be displayed in a web browser.

---

### [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)

> (**D**)ocument
>
> (**O**)bject
>
> (**M**)odel

The **DOM** is a cross-platform and language-independent convention for representing and interacting with objects in **HTML**, XHTML and XML documents. Objects in the **DOM** tree may be addressed and manipulated by using methods on the objects. The public interface of a **DOM** is specified in its application programming interface (API).

---

### [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS)

> (**C**)ascading
>
> (**S**)tyle
>
> (**S**)heets

**CSS** is a style sheet language used for describing the presentation semantics (the look and formatting) of a document written in a markup language. Its most common application is to style web pages written in **HTML** and XHTML, but the language can also be applied to any kind of XML document, including plain XML, SVG and XUL.

---

### [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery)

**jQuery** is a multi-browser **JavaScript** library designed to simplify the client-side scripting of HTML. Used by over 65% of the 10,000 most visited websites, jQuery is the most popular **JavaScript** library in use today.

**jQuery** is free, open source software, licensed under the MIT License. Its syntax is designed to make it easier to navigate a document, select **DOM** elements, create animations, handle events, and develop **AJAX** applications. **jQuery** also provides capabilities for developers to create plug-ins on top of the **JavaScript** library. This enables developers to create abstractions for low-level interaction and animation, advanced effects and high-level, theme-able widgets. The modular approach to the **jQuery** library allows the creation of powerful dynamic web pages and web applications.

The set of **jQuery** core features — **DOM** element selections, traversal and manipulation — enabled by its selector engine (named "Sizzle" from v1.3), created a new "programming style", fusing algorithms and DOM-data-structures; and influenced the architecture of other **JavaScript** frameworks like YUI v3 and Dojo.

---

### [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

> (**A**)synchronous
>
> (**J**)avaScript
>
> (**A**)nd
>
> (**X**)ML

With **AJAX**, web applications can send data to, and retrieve data from, a server asynchronously (in the background) without interfering with the display and behavior of the existing page. Data can be retrieved using the `XMLHttpRequest` object. Despite the name, the use of XML is not required (**JSON** is often used instead), and the requests do not need to be asynchronous.

**AJAX** is not a single technology, but a group of technologies. **HTML** and **CSS** can be used in combination to mark up and style information. The **DOM** is accessed with JavaScript to dynamically display, and allow the user to interact with, the information presented. **JavaScript** and the `XMLHttpRequest` object provide a method for exchanging data asynchronously between browser and server to avoid full page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

To be more accurate that would be what we call Asynchronous Javascript and XML (AJAX). This uses the Document Object Model (DOM) which is a tree that is built from the elements in the web page (think of them as HTML tags if you will). When the events are triggered the AJAX code can the modify this tree directly which in turn affects the code, somewhat.

Also, I would be a fool not to mention [jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492) which is a library that sits on top of AJAX and allows for very easy manipulation of the DOM.

Comment: Right on, I was thinking it might be jQuery as well. Care to elaborate on the DOM concept? This is all new to me, I am planning on learning jQuery and JavaScript pretty soon here (although I have been going back and forth on which one a should learn first). I have read that JavaScript should ideally be learned first, but the fact that spiders have trouble crawling JavaScript has had be second guessing that.

Comment: jQuery is a library using the Javascript language. Obviously you should have basic knowledge of Javascript at least in order to use jQuery.